# How can I get certain columns from a table only if they meet a condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE books
(
    codBook INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title   CHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO books 
VALUES (1, 'Book 1'), (2, 'Book 2'), (3, 'Book 3');

CREATE TABLE people
(
    name    CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(50),
    CP      NUMERIC(5)
);  

INSERT INTO people 
VALUES ('Carl', 'C/X nº 1', '12345'), ('Louis', 'C/X nº 2', '12345'), 
       ('Joseph', 'C/Y nº 3', '12346'), ('Anna', 'C/Z nº 4', '12347');

CREATE TABLE lends
(
    codBook INTEGER REFERENCES books,
    member  CHAR(10) REFERENCES people,
    date    DATE,

    PRIMARY KEY (codBook, member, date)
);

INSERT INTO lends 
VALUES (1, 'Joseph', CURRENT_DATE - 10), 
       (1, 'Carl', CURRENT_DATE - 9), 
       (1, 'Louis', CURRENT_DATE - 8), 
       (2, 'Joseph', CURRENT_DATE - 10);
```

I am trying to get all the rows with the title, address and CP where they were borrowed only if they were borrowed in CP=12345 and the rows that are not from CP 12345 to appear but without the address and the CP. As book 1 has CP 12345 and 12346, I only want it to appear with CP 12345.

My expected solution is:

```
"Book 1";"C/X nº 1";12345
"Book 1";"C/X nº 2";12345
"Book 2";null;null
"Book 3";null;null
```

I tried joining all the tables using 2 left joins:

```
SELECT title, address, CP 
FROM books 
LEFT JOIN lends USING (codBook) 
LEFT JOIN people ON (name = member) 
WHERE CP = 12345;
```

But I only get the rows with CP=12345 and if I remove `WHERE CP=12345` I obtain all the rows, even the book 1 with CP 12346. I am looking for a way to solve this.

Comment: In order to understand your problem domain better, what does "CP" mean or refer-to in this context? I'm not a fan of short, cryptic colum names.

Comment: _"and the books that are not from CP 12345 to appear"_ - I don't understand what you've written here: books don't have a `CP` attribute.

Comment: CP is the postal code and I and I mean the rows where the title of the table books has CP=12345 after joining that table with the other ones, I think maybe I used bad names for the tables

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: On a side note: Always qualify all column names when working with more than one table. This gets the query more readable and maintainable and less prone to errors. You should use short mnemonic table aliases for this, e.g. `LEFT JOIN people p ON p.name = l.member AND p.cp = 12345`. And you should stay consistent with the column names. What is `member? An ID? A name`? A boolean flag? Call it member_name, and it is clear what it is.

Comment: Your WHERE clause turns the outer joins into inner joins, because in an outer joined row the CP is null, so you are dismissing all outer joined rows and only keep the inner joined ones. The typical solution would be to move the condiotion to the ON clause, but as you only want to consider lends where the person is in CP 12345, you should join people and lends first. See nbk's answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you join LENDS and PEOPLE first as `INNER JOIN` and add the CP number to the ON clause you get your result

```
SELECT title , address, CP 
FROM books 
LEFT JOIN (lends 
INNER JOIN people ON (name = member AND CP = 12345))  USING (codBook)
```

| title | address | cp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book 1 | C/X nº 2 | 12345 |
| Book 1 | C/X nº 1 | 12345 |
| Book 2 | *null* | *null* |
| Book 3 | *null* | *null* |

> ```
> SELECT 4
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9PGUGpLz)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will solve your problem:

```
select books.title, sub.address, sub.CP
from books 
left join (
    SELECT address, CP, codbook
    FROM books 
    LEFT JOIN lends USING (codBook) 
    JOIN people ON (name = member and CP = 12345) 
) as sub on books.codbook = sub.codbook
```